# Remote controlled RS232 switching

Tags: arduino, switches, rs232

A mission critical fire alarm system has a GSM module that is connected via RS232 to a computer whose task is to notify emergency response teams. In case the computer fails, an off-site operator is notified and he needs to switch to a backup computer within a minute. What I'm looking for is a solution this operator can use to remotely "unplug" the RS232 cable and "plug" it to the other computer. (I was informed that splitting the cable was not a reliable option.)

I'm looking for cheap commercial solutions (found [this](http://www.dcbnet.com/datasheet/unsw.html) for $1300) or building something with Arduino. The important part is that it after a handshake is established, it should forward communication transparently and reliably.

The remote control part is nothing fancy: it is entirely possible to plug the device to a third computer on site and access its interface program via remote desktop. So USB control is fine as well as Ethernet access and a mini Web server.

My electronics knowledge level is rather low: I can solder some well documented digital chips together with some capacitors and resistors on a protoboard but I could never figure out their values myself or design any analog circuit containing more than one transistor. Please take that into account in your response. :)

Comment: The switching part can be done with a relay. But reliability-enigineering-wise, I would consider adding a second GSM module!

Comment: Unfortunately that would mean modifying the setup of hundreds if not thousands of sites countrywide to send their alerts to two GSM numbers.

Comment: Ah, the GSM is at the receiving end, my impression was that it was at the sending end. Every answer gives rise to a new question :) : how does that remote operator know that the computer has failed? It seems more reliable to let some electronics decide that locally and do the switching (using a relay) automatically.

Comment: You write 'mission critical', this means that whenever the mechanism would fail during a fire, it will cost you a huge sum of money. Why are you looking at a cheap solution for a mission critical problem? How often does this guy need to go out to swap cables and why not tackle the unreliable computer first? If that is not an option, invite the supplier of the system to come and collect his equipment and buy from someone else.

Comment: Wouter: I don't really know the details, I'm guessing SNMP. Failure can be a software crash too, which is difficult to detect with just electronics.

Comment: jippie: Above all I'm looking for a reliable solution. Cheap is a plus. The one I mentioned in the question is surely expensive and the company website looks like coming from the 90's which doesn't exactly build trust. :) At this phase I'm looking for options to consider. Building it myself would be a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

Cheap two port serial switches are are sold as KvM's (Keyboard, Video, Mouse). adding the cost of serial-mouse and mouse-serial adapters will still bring the price in under $100.

However:
When the gsm module goes offline, the telephone network should be set to automatically forward calls to the  backup number. So all you have to do is make sure that the gsm module power goes off when the computer fails. You can buy a computer controlled power switch to do that.

This does not require any modification to the sites, and can even be put at a separate site.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to such an adapter? I only know USB to PS/2 mouse adapters, never heard of a serial to mouse adapter.

Comment: Also would be interested in a KvM switch model whose output can be remotely switched from one PC to another.